# OpenCV-Python VideoCapture only loads part of video

Tags: python, opencv, video, loading, frame

I am currently trying to load a ultra-HD video (3840 × 2160) frame-by-frame using OpenCV in Python. I am using the `VideoCapture` object from the OpenCV library, and it seems to work fine except for the fact, that it only loads 26 frames.

The video is a **8:54** minutes long **.mp4** with **30fps** and **H.264** coding.

A simplification of my code looks like the following

```
import cv2

def get_frames(filepath):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, frame = cap.read()

        if not success: 
            break

        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        yield frame
```

The code seems to work fine for other videos at lower resolution.
I use Python 3.5.1 and version 3.1.0 of cv2.

Has anyone experienced the same problem or can recommend any other library for fast loading of video frames in Python?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

According to VLC's Median Information the video have the following properties:

```
Codec:              H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc 1)
Resolution:         3840x2178
Display resolution: 3840x2160
Frame rate:         29.970030
Decoded format:     Planar 4:2:0 YUV full scale
```

I tried converting the movie first using `ffmpeg` with the following command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -crf 18 video_converted.mp4
```

which actually made the code work even though the properties are exactly the same (according to VLC).

Comment: Can you post the example of video?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to publicly post the video, but I have editted my question with some more details.